# Live bytes growing at cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TRSocialCell *cell = (TRSocialCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TRSocialCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        __weak TREvent *eventFromParse;
        if (!isSearchingEvents){
            if ( [filteredArray[indexPath.section] count] == 0) {
                [cell displayForNoEvents];
                cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgCell;
                return cell;
            } else {
                eventFromParse = filteredArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
            }
        }
        else eventFromParse = searched[indexPath.row];

        //Cover Image
        [eventFromParse.fileForCover getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                eventFromParse.coverPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                cell.coverView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            } else {
                [TRAppDelegate displayInternetErrorForView:self.view];
            }

        }];

        cell.titleAutoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventFromParse.title];
        cell.titleAutoLabel.fadeLength = 0;
        cell.titleAutoLabel.pauseInterval = 2.0f;
        [animatedLabels addObject:cell.titleAutoLabel];

        if (eventFromParse.location != nil) {
            cell.addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventFromParse.location.name];
        }

        [cell.titleAutoLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BigNoodleTitling" size:26]];
        [cell.titleAutoLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.addressLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BigNoodleTitling" size:18]];
        [cell.addressLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BigNoodleTitling" size:18]];
        [cell.dateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[TRAppDelegate convertDateToDate:eventFromParse.date],[TRAppDelegate convertDateToTime:eventFromParse.date]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgCell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I'm having trouble cause memory is growing but i can't find what is. Is it normal the if (!cell) {} keep beign called everytime I scroll to another cell?

Do I have to set properties to nil in a view controller's dealloc?

What is problably leaking is this code?

Comment: Short answer: No, it should only be called for the first few cells to be displayed on screen, then it should reuse a pre-existing cell.  By the way, here is a proper pattern for setting data on a cell (you're using the old way... the new way uses prototype cells which does away with the `if (cell == nil)` check) https://gist.github.com/iwasrobbed/1656ddf1b0ca645bd123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble cause memory is growing but i can't find what is. Is it normal the if (!cell) {} keep beign called everytime I scroll to another cell?

Nope. You didn't put the newly allocated cells in the reuse queue. So every time you need to provide a new cell you're basically loading a new nib into RAM. The way you do it, the new `TRSocialCell`s have no idea what their reuse identifier is - and therefore they obviously do not get reused at all.

Try implementing the following method inside your `TRSocialCell` implementation file, so your cells can return their `reuseIdentifier` when being asked by system:

```
- (NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
   return @"cell";
}
```

By the way:
'cell' isn't the cleverest choice for a `reuseIdentifier`. In case you want to use cells of a different type someday it can really mess up your reuse queue. It would recommend you to include the class name in the identifier. For example `TRSocialCellID`

Comment: Thanks! I changed the reuse identifier and deleted the prototype cells! And BAM! It worked. Thanks again.